# Always find the middle of a string with elements grouped by 3 characters

Tags: string, math

I've a series of strings that represent airline's itineraries:

```
FLROTP
MADFCOFCOFLR
BLQMADMADUIOUIOMADMADBLQ
MXPJFKJFKMCOJFKMXP
WAWPSAPSAWAW
FLRFRAFRASGNSGNBKKBKKVIEVIEFLR
FLRMUCMUCDELDXBDXBZRHZRHFLR
FLRFRAFRASINSINMELMELSINSINFRAFRAFLR
FLRCDGCDGCANCANJJNZHACANCANCDGCDGFLRWNZCANCANZHAHKGAMSFLR
JFKMTYMTYMEXMEXPTYMDEMDEBOGBOGLIM
PSAISTISTICNICNNRTNRTISTISTPSANRTISTISTPSA
MXPDXBDXBPERPERADLADLMELMELASPASPAYQAYQASPASPSYDSYDDXBDXBMXP
FLRFRAFRAORDORDLASLASBNACLTCLTMUCMUCPSA
FLRCDGCDGBOGBOGBAQBAQBOGBOGCUCCUCBOGBOGMDEMDEBOGBOGUIOGYELIMLIMHAVHAVCDGCDGFLR
FLRFRAFRALAXLAXSEASEAORDORDICTICTORDORDCMHCMHBOSBOSMIAMIAFRAFRAFLR
PSAMUCMUCIADIADGSOGSOCLTCLTMIAMIADFWDFWICTICTDFWDFWCMHCMHPHLPHLALBALBIADIADFRAFRAFLR
FLRFRAFRAEZEEZESCLSCLGRUCGHSDUSDUPOAPOAGRUGRULIMLIMUIOUIOBOGBOGPTYPTYPOSPOSMIAMIAFRAFRAFLR
PSACDGCDGHAVHAVPTYPTYUIOUIOMDEMDEBOGBOGBAQBAQBOGBOGCUCCUCBOGBOGCDGCDGFLR
FLRCDGCDGMEXMEXSJOSJOMEXBJXBJXMEXMEXCDGCDGPSA
```

I'd like to always be able to find the "middle" of the string (that 90% of the cases is the passenger's destination) but i'm short of ideas. Any help? :)

Comment: what is the middle of a `string`?

Comment: The question is very unclear, but fun. Try [`^(.*)(?:(.+)\2+)?(.*?)\2?\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/lN5bB9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not the index at the exact middle of the string, but the closest index to the middle that is a multiple of 3, to index the start of a valid 3-letter code.

You didn't specify a language so I'll just use C++ to illustrate.

```
std::string code = "MXPJFKJFKMCOJFKMXP";
```

Find the length of the string:

```
int length = code.size();
```

Count how many codes you have:

```
int codecount = length / 3;
```

Find the middle code, using integer arithmetic (rounding down), with the codes numbered from zero:

```
int middlecode = codecount / 2;
```

Find the start index of your middle code:

```
int index = middlecode * 3;
```

Get the middle code:

```
std::string destination = code.substr(index, 3);
```

For strings with an even number of codes, this will give the first code in the second half of the string, e.g:

MXPJFKJFK**MCO**JFKMXP

For strings with an odd number of codes, this will give the middle code, e.g:

FLRFRAFRAORDORDLAS**LAS**BNACLTCLTMUCMUCPSA

(which in the above case looks wrong, but you did say only 90%!)

Comment: Looks exactly what i wanted :D

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment.